# C++ dynamic array of matrices (from scythe statistical library)

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the scythe statistical library (found here: http://scythe.wustl.edu/).  I can initialize a matrix just fine with:

```
Matrix<double> A(2, 2, false);
```

But I would like to have a dynamic array of such matrices.  Does anyone have any hints?  Do I use vector?  If so how?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, use a vector.  Assuming of course that Matrix<> meets the requirements (assignable, copyable, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `std::vector` would be an excellent choice, especially if you don't know until runtime how many matrices you need.  For example,

```
std::vector<Matrix<double> > vectorOfMatrices;

vectorOfMatrices.push_back(Matrix<double>(2, 2, false));
// etc.
```

Comment: yep.  That's perfect.  As you can tell, I'm a bit of a newb.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes suitable for your task:

a) std::vector - stores the objects in an array, can be accessed via index as well as iterator. Good for random access operations.

b) std::list - stores objects as a linked-list, accessed via iterators. Good for sequential-only access and frequent modifications.

So, if you just want an array of fixed or only rarely-changing size, go for std::vector. However, if you know these will change rather often, and you typically iterate over the whole thing, std::list is a better alternative.